# Could NOT find PythonLibs, anaconda3

Tags: python, c++, boost, cmake, anaconda

ORIGINAL POST:

I am trying to compile a simple 'hello world' to call from python (anaconda3), complied using CMake.

I get:

```
Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

hello.cpp:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <string>

std::string greet(std::string name){
    return std::string("Hello, ") + name;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello){
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet, "Prepends a greeting to the passed name");
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
find_package(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)

set(BOOST_PYTHONLIB python-py36)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS ${BOOST_PYTHONLIB})

python_add_module(hello hello.cpp)
target_include_directories(hello PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(hello ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

Crucally, I'm trying to use anaconda3, so based on some other posts I've added the following arguments for when CMake is called:

```
-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/Users/chris/anaconda3/lib
-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/Users/chris/anaconda3/include
```

But I get the same error with or without these arguments. I'm still relatively new to this, so apologies if this is something trivial.

I'm running Mojave 10.14.6, and I'm doing this through CLion.

UPDATE:

As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445169/pythonlibs3-cmake-and-macos)post, editing the package finds to

```
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonInterp 3)
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs 3)
```

Seems to help - it finds PythonLibs but not the correct one.

```
Could NOT find PythonLibs: Found unsuitable version "2.7.10", but required is at least "3" (found /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib)
```

I am aware that I can (in principle) do:

```
set(PYTHON_LIBRARIES /Users/chris/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib)
```

As discussed in the comments, which does find the correct library, but as discussed in the above post, later gives me the error `Unknown CMake command "PYTHON_ADD_MODULE".`

According to that post, the "reason for this appears to be because this function is provided by FindPythonLibs.cmake which is loaded in by find_package(Pythonlibs) and therefore, if this is not used to located PythonLibs, this function cannot be called".

So, it seems that the path to `/Users/chris/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib` needs to be somehow added to FindPackage()s search. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: "But I get the same error with or without these arguments." - That is, even when you set `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR` variable, the error message you got still contains `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS` as missing? Are you sure? As for `PYTHON_LIBRARY` variable setting, it should contain path to the library **file**, not a *directory*, as you currently have (`/Users/chris/anaconda3/lib`).

Comment: What should the library file be called? I have `/Users/chris/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib`, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, file `/Users/chris/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib` looks OK for being a python library.

Comment: I can't just set the variable PYTHON_LIBRARIES to this for reasons I've explained in the update above.